# how to change div size in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have css class as "brands" now I need change size of thumbnail div in brand class how can I do this?

```
<div class="brands">
    <div class="row">
        <?php foreach ($item['brands'] as $key => $value): ?>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/img/logos/<?php echo sprintf("%s-logo.jpg", $value); ?>" alt="<?php echo sprintf('%s Logo Image', ucwords($value)); ?>" />
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can add this code in css files:

.thumbnail {width: 100%;}

Answer (score 0):

This will overwrite only .thumbnails elements inside .brands class

```
.brands .thumbnail {
    width: yourWidth;
    height: youtHeight;
}
```

Comment: seriously you even know CSS ??